# What's wrong with this LINQ, converting one object to another?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, select

I'm trying to have a one-liner LINQ statement to project my one object to my ViewModel object - it seems it won't work with `select`?? The compiler says `cannot resolve symbol select`. This works with a collection, why doesn't it here? If not `select`, what keyword am I missing?

```
return from p in SettingRepository.Get(id)
       select new EditSetting
                {

                };
```

**Edit** - Scratch that, doesn't work for a list. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work for a list? What you have will work perfectly fine for a list.

Comment: What's the return type of `SettingRepository.Get()`?

Comment: @SinaIravanian it is an Entity Framework object.

Comment: if `SettingRepository.Get()` returns `EntityObject`, surely it wont work. `Select()` is available for collections like `IEnumerable<T>`, `IQueryable<T>`, `IObjectSet<T>` etc

Comment: Yes it is one `EntityObject`. Is there a way to do this without `Select`?

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not sure why you would want to use `select` to do this, but if you're really adamant about it:

```
return from p in new List<EntityObject>{SettingRepository.Get(id)}
       select new EditSetting
                {

                };
```

If not, why not just use good old initializers?

```
var editSetting= new EditSetting { Id = setting.Id };
```

Comment: agreed. However Bryan has neglected to go over the reasons this is bad. Typically I see a lot of tight looping of code on `.Get(id)` which when used on EF means `O(n)` database IO hits, severely impacting performance.

Answer (score 1):

Typically I prefer to create methods with the following pattern. It discourages tight looping of Database calls, which can severely limit performance. Still Bryan Hong's answer is the actual ANSWER to your question.

```
public IQueryable<EditSetting> GetEditSettings()
{
    return from p in SettingRepository
        select new EditSetting{
                Foo = p.Foo,
                Bar = p.Bar,
                //etc...
        };
}
```

or

```
public IEnumerable<EditSetting> GetEditSettingsById(IList<string> ids)
{
    var ret =  from p in SettingRepository
            where ids.Contains(p.Id)
            select new EditSetting{
                    Foo = p.Foo,
                    Bar = p.Bar,
                    //etc...
            };
    return ret.ToList();
}
```